# Android: Expressing and rendering Mathematical equation

Tags: android, math, equation

We need to express & render all mathematical equations (e.g. fractions, algebraic equations, matrix, calculus, trigonometry) in the our Android Native Application [not a web/browser application].

(a)Is there a way to do the same using Android libraries? For eg for desktop/server Java based JLatexMath can be used. Is there similar option available for Android? How can something similar be done on the Android platform?
There were some similar questions asked but the answer to them referred to libraries that can not be used on Android.

(b) If native libraries are not there, then how easy/difficult will it be to use Android web-view to provide support for equations expression and rendering. Will it possible to use java script libraries like jsMath?

In this case, i plan to generate HTML code on the fly and refer jsMath library. Will this have any issues?

(c)  In our application, there are some action that needs to be performed based on user event for an equation. If web view based approach is used, then how can it trigger processing in native part of our application. Is there any thing special consideration while calling application native code from javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

I used MathJax in my android app. It renders mathematical expression offline, which means you don't need network connection.

You might find this link helpful. 
http://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: Shakti> But its a webview?

Comment: You can use it in an android app also. I am using it in one of my native app.

Comment: Shakti> yes, i guess you are including the webview inside your native app... so that is not native. Or am i mistaken?

Comment: Yes Its a webview inside a native app :) I